What's wrong with this "counter-example" of Baire's Theorem?
Yesterday my teacher had taught us the Baire Space, that is, a topological space where the intersection of countably many dense open subsets is always dense.
I immediately came up with an example of dense open subsets on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, that is, let $Q_{2^a (2b-1)}=\dfrac{a}{b}(a\in \mathbb N,b\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1})$, and $U_n=\bigcup\limits_{i\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}} \mathopen] Q_i ,Q_i+2^{-n-i}\mathclose[$ when $n\in \mathbb N$.
I "proved" that $\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n=\varnothing$ by $\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\limits_{i\in \mathbb N}]Q_i,Q_i+2^{-n-i}[=\bigcup\limits_{i\in \mathbb N}\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} ]Q_i,Q_i+2^{-n-i}[=\bigcup\limits_{i\in \mathbb N}\varnothing=\varnothing$.
The teacher had told me that the $\bigcup$ and the $\bigcap$ can't be swapped here. Now I know that my "proof" is problematic, and according to Baire's theorem, $\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}U_n$ is dense in $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.
But I failed to find any number in it. Can someone give me a number in $\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n$ to prove that it's not empty?

With things like this, you often need Zorn's Lemma / axiom of choice to provide a non-constructive example. Maybe you can use that?

Do I understand correctly that $Q_i$ is just an enumeration of the rationals? Then for fixed $n$ the set $U_n$ contains at least all the irrational numbers.

@Lieven yes, $Q_i$ is just an enumeration. I don’t know how did you say so, but it’s clear the Lebesgue measure of the set should be zero.

By the way, a simpler example showing that swapping the union and intersection is invalid is $\bigcap_n \bigcup_i ]\frac{-i}n,\frac in[ = \Bbb R$ but $\bigcup_i \bigcap_n ]\frac{-i}n,\frac in[ = {0}$. (They can't even be swapped in general for finite collections of sets—I encourage you to find a simple counterexample.)

Take $Q'_i$ to be a bounded subsequence of $Q_i$. Next pick $r_i$ as any element of $(Q'_i, Q'i + a{n,i})$ close enough to $Q'i$, i.e. so that $(r_i)$ is bounded as well. I can pick $n=i$ because it is decreasing in $n$. So it is a kind of diagonal argument. Therefore it has a convergent subsequence. I'm think that the limit belongs to all $U_n$. Here the only relevant properties are that $Q$ has a bounded subsequence and that $a{n,i}$ is bounded and decreasing in first variable.

Comparing sets to arithmetic union is like addition and intersection like multiplication, some old notations actually use the arithmetic notation for sets in this way. Anyway, the operations do not commute as you can easily find examples that illustrate.

I won't be actually providing an example of a point in $\bigcap_n U_n$ (I don't know how to do that).  Rather, I'll be able to provide a relatively simple proof that such a point exists and in doing so I'll give a deterministic algorithm to approximate said point.
To start, denote $$I_n(i) := \left]Q_i, Q_i + 2^{-n-i}\right[,$$ and to any interval $I = \left]a, b\right[$, associate the closed "middle half" interval $$F(I) = \left[\frac{3a+b}4, \frac{a+3b}4\right].$$
With this notation in mind, here's a lemma:

For any $i,n$, there is some $j$ such that $Q_j \in \left[Q_i+2^{-n-i-2}, Q_i+2^{-n-i-1}\right]$ and $j \geq i+1$.  For such $j$, $I_{n+1}(j) \subset F(I_n(i))$.

The first part of this lemma follows because the interval in which we look for $Q_j$ has infinitely many rational numbers and all but finitely many $j$ satisfies $j \geq i+1$.
The second part follows from the inequalities $$\frac34Q_i + \frac{1}{4}(Q_i + 2^{-n-i}) = Q_i + 2^{-n-i-2} \leq Q_j \\ Q_j + 2^{-(n+1)-j} \leq Q_i+2^{-n-i-1} + 2^{-(n+1)-(i+1)} = \frac14Q_i + \frac34(Q_i + 2^{-n-i})$$

With the above in mind, I'll now prove

For any $i_0\geq 1$ and $m \geq 0$, we have $I_m(i_0) \cap \bigcap_n U_n \neq \varnothing$.

Define a sequence $(i_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ as follows: For $n \leq m$, define $i_n = i_0$.  For $n \geq m$, inductively define $i_{n+1}$ to be the smallest $j \geq i_n + 1$ such that $I_{n+1}(j) \subset F(I_n(i_n))$.
Note that
$$\begin{align*}F(I_{n+1}(i_{n+1})) &\subseteq I_{n+1}(i_{n+1}) \\ &\subseteq F(I_n(i_n)) \\ &\subseteq I_m(i_0) \cap I_n(i_n) \\ &\subseteq I_m(i_0) \cap U_n\end{align*}$$
for every $n$, so that $$\bigcap_n F(I_n(i_n)) \subseteq I_m(i_0) \cap \bigcap_n U_n.$$
The above sequence of inclusions also shows $\Big(F(I_n(i_n))\Big)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of bounded, closed intervals, so by a compactness argument, they have non-empty intersection, which completes the proof.
As a final note, the above actually gives an alternative proof that $\bigcap_n U_n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.  Do you see why?
